# Eclipse ADT - Native debug

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

On my Windows 7 platform, I have the latest version of adt bundle (20140321) and ndk (r9d) installed. The installation is as clean as it gets. The environment variables NDK_ROOT, PATH, etc. are all defined properly.

The application that I am working on has some native code that gets built with armeabi-v7a ABI. The app platform is andorid-19. Project settings define build as "ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1."

From Eclipe, when I debug my application on my samsung tablet as "Android Java Application," everything works as expected. However, when I try to debug the app as "Android Native Application," I get the following error:

```
Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.mycomp.myapp' on port 8604
gdbserver output:
Cannot attach to lwp 28275: Operation not permitted (1)

Exiting

Verify if the application was built with NDK_DEBUG=1
```

The application runs fine on the device though.

I have looked at various messages on stackoverflow. However, I could not find any concrete step to fix this problem. Would appreciate if you can guide me in the right direction. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. After wasting some time I found that when I return my simple function without any operation problem does not occurs.

```
void dmpBuffer(char* msg, unsigned char* buffer, int buffLen)
{
    //return;
    char szDumpBuffer[128];
    for(int i=0; i<buffLen; i++)
        sscanf(&szDumpBuffer[i*2], "%02X", buffer[i]);
    LOGE("%s:%s", msg, szDumpBuffer);
}
```

maybe it is because of memory problems.

**Update:**
As I had Guessed it was memory problem.
My BIG mistake was using sscanf instead of sprintf!!!
My problem solved.

Comment: As you wish. it was experience sharing not fully answer.